# How to add nginx type configs to react native web rponect?

Tags: react-native, nginx, nginx-config, react-native-web

With a react-native-web project, there's a `nginx.conf` file.

I've tried adding the `type` block to this file (both in and out of the `server` block) in order to get `mjs` files to be served as `application/javascript`. However this does not seem to be respected as the files are still served as `text/html`.